# Por qué no me funciona mi bucle for javascript? Cogiendo una variable java dada anteriormente

Tags: javascript, java

estoy intentando recorrer una lista y llamarla desde una funcion javascript pero el iterador i  no me lo reconoce, me recorre bien el for pero no me muestra los elementos de la lista ¿ sabéis que podría ser?

```
    <%
        XMLOficinas[] oficinas= tdatos.getXMLOficinas();
        
    %>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function continuar(){   
    
        if (<%=oficinas.length%> > 0) {
            var total=0;
            for (var i = 0; i < <%=oficinas.length%>; i++){
                 alert(<%=oficinas[i].codigo%>);
            }
        }
}
    </script>
```

Me da este error como que no reconoce la i:

```
    Ha tenido lugar un error en la línea: 68 en el archivo jsp: /oficinas.jsp
    i cannot be resolved to a variable
    65:     if (<%=oficinas.length%> > 0) {
    66:         var total=0;
    67:         for (var i = 0; i < <%=oficinas.length%>; i++){
    68:             alert(<%=oficinas[i].codigo%>);
    69:         }
    70:     }
    71:
```

¿Cómo se escapa en esos casos la i en javascript?

Y para escapar este otro caso donde pongo variable que recibiré del for anterior:

```
var oficina= $('[name="<%=PREFIJO%>variable"]').val();
```

Un saludo, muchas gracias !!

Sé el problema pero no se como arreglarlo, lo que pretendo es coger el valor de una variable que contengo un array con codigos que necesito para luego en javascript recoger el valor de varios input pintados que se han formado con un prefijo y ese código  ( % de participacion que necesito para sumarlos y lanzar un alert), y resumiendo no sé como recorrer ese array que viene de java

<%
XMLOficinas[] oficinas= tdatos.getXMLOficinas();

```
%>
<script type="text/javascript">

function continuar(){   

    if (<%=oficinas.length%> > 0) {
        var total=0;
        for (var i = 0; i < <%=oficinas.length%>; i++){
             alert(<%=oficinas[i].codigo%>);
        }
    }
```

}

Y unido a la segunda pregunta:

var oficina= $('[name="<%=PREFIJO%>variable"]').val(); donde la variable seria el codigo que estoy ahora mostrando en el alert, algo así como:

function continuar(){

```
    if (<%=oficinas.length%> > 0) {
        var total=0;
        for (var i = 0; i < <%=oficinas.length%>; i++){
             $('[name="<%=PREFIJO%>oficinas[i]"]').val();
        }
    }
```

}

Si lanzo un alert de esto:
$('[name="PRE_48"]').val();
obtengo un valor que luego queria ir sumando

No se si me he explicado mas o menos bien pero en esas ando....buscando y enterandome como escapar o que el codigo se lea y funcione correctamente

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! esto es jsp no? entonces deberias hacer el for en jsp.. jsp se ejecuta del lado del servidor, javascript del lado del cliente...

Comment: Te falta una llave de cierre `}` en tu función JS y yo, por pura salud mental (propia), declararía explícitamente que el script es `type="text/javascript"`

Comment: Si perdona ahora lo edito, realmente tiene la llave y lo de javascript pero muchas gracisa igualmente

Comment: @Alfabravo, parece que la especificación de HTML5 recomienda no usar el [atributo type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-type) para evitar redundancias. Supongo que era útil es especificaciones anteriores y navegadores antiguos.

Comment: @Triby gracias por la aclaración. Se le nota a uno la vejez :)

Comment: @Manuel la idea es que el ejemplo sea verificable para que no recibas N comentarios sobre problemas tipográficos u otras cosas menores y se descarten de plano.

Comment: El problema (mas alla de todo) esta en que trata de leer desde jsp, una variabla declarada en js.. son dos ambientes distintos... Lo que se necesita es saber que tratas de hacer con este codigo, que seguro no es tirar un monton de alerts en el navegador....

Comment: OK tomo nota, mil gracias

Comment: @gbianchi Buen punto. Está usando la i de javascript en el array java.